# Python function not successful to define variable

Tags: python, python-exec

I have run the below code:

```
def test(yymm):
    exec("test_var_" + yymm + " = 'abc'")
    print(test_var_1912)

test('1912')
```

My expected output is to assign the variable '**test_var_1912**' and print out string "**abc**". However, Python prompt the below error message:

> NameError: name 'test_var_1912' is not defined

Could anyone please help to solve my question?

Comment: You cannot use `exec` or `eval` to assign to the local namespace. But you never have to. What are you *actually trying to do*?

Comment: use dictionary to keep it - `test_var = dict()`, `test_var["1912"] = 'abc'` - `print(test_var["1912"])`

Comment: @furas that will work, but again, *almost certainly* there is a way to accomplish it without `exec` that will be more elegant and less brittle.

Comment: @furas You can keep the dynamic variable in special `globals()` dict like this `exec("test_var_" + yymm + " = 'abc'", globals())`

Comment: @ThànhChungBùi all languages have dictionary for this and using `global` and `exec` is not good idea.